# Why is the != operator faster than the = operator?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database and I perform the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    category,
    name,
    COUNT(side.id) as nb
FROM main
LEFT JOIN side
    ON main.id = side.id_main
WHERE category != 3
GROUP BY category, name;
```

This query takes around 0.3 seconds and returns 8000 rows.
Here is the associated query plan:

```
id  parent  notused detail
7   0   0   SCAN TABLE main USING COVERING INDEX idx_main
19  0   0   SEARCH TABLE side USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (id_main=?)
```

Now, I would like to select only one category. So, I rewrote my `WHERE` clause like this:

```sql
SELECT
    category,
    name,
    COUNT(side.id) as nb
FROM main
LEFT JOIN side
    ON main.id = side.id_main
WHERE category = 1
GROUP BY category, name;
```

This query takes now around 43 seconds and returns 5000 rows! It is 100 times longer!
Here is the associated query plan:

```
id  parent  notused detail
7   0   0   SEARCH TABLE main USING COVERING INDEX idx_main (category=?)
11  0   0   SCAN TABLE side
```

Why is the equals operator so slow? Is there anything wrong in my query?

---

Reproduction steps:

1. Create the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE main (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
category INTEGER,
name VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE side (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
id_main INTEGER
);

CREATE INDEX idx_side ON side (id, id_main);

CREATE INDEX idx_main ON main (category, name);
```

2. Use the following Perl script to populate the tables

```perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=file.db","","");

my $v = 'A';

for my $i (1..9000) {
    my $category = 1;
    $category = 2 if $i > 5000;
    $category = 3 if $i > 8000;
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO main(category, name) VALUES($category, '$v')");
    $v++;
}

for my $i (1..100000) {
    my $r = int(rand() * 9000 + 1);
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO side(id_main) VALUES($r)");
}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, update the post with explain plans for both "!=" and "=" queries please. Here you may find how to get those https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: Yes, please run `EXPLAIN` on both queries.  What you are seeing seems very counterintuitive to me (but +1 to a good question).

Comment: @ekochergin Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the first step is understandable : `=` allow SQLite to look up the rows for the given value (`SEARCH`) while `!=` requires it to go through all the values (`SCAN`)

The question is : Why does it create a temporary (`AUTOMATIC`) index (which happen to be very effective) in the first case, not in the second ?

I think it's because, without additional informations, the query planner assumes that an `=` clause will yield fewer matches than a `!=`, and the cost of building a temporary index is not justified.

The solution is to let SQLite gather information with [ANALYZE](https://sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html). The query plan becomes :

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH TABLE main USING COVERING INDEX idx_main (category=?)
`--SEARCH TABLE side USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (id_main=?)
```

Another solution is create the required index, so that SQLite doesn't have to build it.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_side2 ON side (id_main);
```

With the following query plan (even without analyse) :

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH TABLE main USING COVERING INDEX idx_main (category=?)
`--SEARCH TABLE side USING COVERING INDEX idx_side2 (id_main=?)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the interesting question and for explain plans.

The plans showing us why "!=" takes less time to run than "=" query.

The "!=" query scans idx_main index to get data and then looks for respective lines in "side" table using another index, which has been automatically created. So, I see it like database just fully scanned an index and then searched for suitable data in another index.

The "=" query though starts with searching for lines having category=1 using index and then full scans entire "side" table which takes long time because it needs to check every single tuple in that table.